# Pexpect: async expect with several connection

Tags: python, asynchronous, pexpect

I'm trying to write script for gathering some information from network devices using Pexpect async expect(python 3.5.1 and pexpect from github) and get some strange thing: all works fine with several devices and doesn't work with some more (usually > 5-6). I wrote this simple script for testing:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def test_ssh_expect_async(num):
    print('Task #{0} start'.format(num))
    p = pexpect.spawn('ssh localhost', encoding='utf8')
    #p.logfile = sys.stdout
    yield from p.expect('password', async=True)
    p.sendline('***')
    yield from p.expect(r'@self-VirtualBox\:', async=True)
    p.sendline('uptime')
    yield from p.expect(r'@self-VirtualBox\:', async=True)
    p.sendline('uname -a')
    yield from p.expect(r'@self-VirtualBox\:', async=True)
    p.sendline('ll')
    yield from p.expect(r'@self-VirtualBox\:', async=True)
    print('Task #{0} end'.format(num))

@asyncio.coroutine
def test_loop():
    tasks = []
    for i in range(1, 5):
        tasks.append(test_ssh_expect_async(i))
    yield from asyncio.wait(tasks)
    print('All Tasks done')


print('--------------Async--------------------')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(test_loop())
```

If i try to use range(1,3) as example i get this:

```
self@self-VirtualBox:/media/sf_netdev$ python3 simple-test.py 
--------------Async--------------------
Task #3 running
Task #1 running
Task #2 running
Task #3 closed
Task #1 closed
Task #2 closed
All Tasks done
```

But if i increase upper limit i get some errors:

```
self@self-VirtualBox:/media/sf_netdev$ python3 simple-test.py 
--------------Async--------------------
Task #3 running
Task #1 running
Task #4 running
Task #2 running
Exception in callback BaseSelectorEventLoop.add_reader(11, <bound method...d=11 polling>>)
handle: <Handle BaseSelectorEventLoop.add_reader(11, <bound method...d=11 polling>>)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 234, in add_reader
    key = self._selector.get_key(fd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/selectors.py", line 191, in get_key
    raise KeyError("{!r} is not registered".format(fileobj)) from None
KeyError: '11 is not registered'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
...
```

Why it happens? How to write working script with async pexpect?

---------------Answer------------

It was a bug https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/issues/347. Now pexpect command fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/issues/347. Now pexpect command fixed it.

Comment: Please edit the essential contents into this answer and then accept it as the answer to your question.